# Yocto: Manipulating users/groups in helper class with fakeroot/pseudo

Tags: yocto, fakeroot

**Introduction**

I wrote a class, call it `persist-conf-files`, whose purpose is to migrate certain files installed by standard recipes into a different directory and create symbolic links to those files for persistence.

The reason for this is to have a disk partition layout with a read-only, replaceable rootfs partition and a persistent storage partition. The idea is to move certain configuration files installed by a recipe into persistent storage and replace the rootfs version with a symlink. That way when the rootfs is upgraded, the symlink will point to the persistent version.

The solution should retain UID and GID settings, even those made by the `useradd` class. An example might be a configuration file for a system daemon service that should run as its own user and group rather than run as root.

The user inherits this class in a `.bbappend` file in another layer and specifies the list of files that should have this treatment inside a `PERSIST_CONF_FILES` variable.

The problem is that UID and GID settings are not transferred properly to the destination file.

Note that I posted a similar [question](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/g/yocto/topic/91739241#57328) to the Yocto mailing list last year that received no responses. I've added more context and details to this question.

**Implementation**

I implemented this logic in a Python function and added it as a task as follows. I abstracted away some details. This class should move `/etc/example.conf` to `/persistent/example.conf` while maintaining its UID and GID.

In the base recipe at `meta-another-layer/recipes-support/some-package/some-package_0.1.bb`:

```
FILES:${PN} += "${sysconfdir}/example.conf"

inherit useradd
USERADD_PACKAGES = "${PN}"
USERADD_PARAM:${PN} = "--system --home-dir /run/some_package \
                       --no-create-home --shell /sbin/nologin \
                       --user-group some_package \
                      "

do_install:append() {
    install -m 0640 ${S}/example.conf ${D}${sysconfdir}/example.conf
    chgrp -R some_package ${D}${sysconfdir}/example.conf
}
```

In the bbappend file in my own layer at `meta-my-layer/recipes-support/some-package/some-package_%.bbappend`:

```
PERSIST_CONF_FILES = "${sysconfdir}/example.conf"
inherit persist-conf-files
```

In the bbclass file at `meta-my-layer/classes/persist-conf-files.bbclass`:

```
fakeroot python persist_conf_files_copy_and_symlink() {
    import os
    import shutil
...
    for conffile in d.getVar('PERSIST_CONF_FILES').split():
        # get the path relative to `/etc`
        relfile = os.path.relpath(conffile, d.getVar('sysconfdir'))

        # compute the absolute paths to source `/etc` and destination `/persistent`
        sysconfdir_absfile = os.path.join(d.getVar('D'), d.getVar('sysconfdir'), relfile)
        destdir_absfile = os.path.join(d.getVar('D'), 'persistent', relfile)

        # copy the file including all permissions and UID/GID settings
        st = os.stat(sysconfdir_absfile)
        shutil.copy(sysconfdir_absfile, destdir_absfile)
        shutil.chown(destdir_absfile, user=st.st_uid, group=st.st_gid)

        # omitted: replace the original file with a symlink to the copied file
...

}

persist_conf_files_copy_and_symlink[depends] += "virtual/fakeroot-native:do_populate_sysroot"

do_install[postfuncs] += "${PERSISTCONFFILESINSTALLFUNCS}"

PERSISTCONFFILESINSTALLFUNCS_class-target = "persist_conf_files_copy_and_symlink"
PERSISTCONFFILESINSTALLFUNCS = ""
```

**Problem**

The problem I'm having is that UID and GID don't seem to be available to the `shutil.chown` function or they're not read correctly from the pseudo database when `os.stat` is called. Using the function as shown above, `persist-conf-files.bbclass` doesn't preserve the UID/GID of the original file (as known to fakeroot/pseudo) and falls back to setting UID:GID=root:root on the copied file instead. During build, bitbake prints a warning like this when building the `some-package` recipe:

```
"warning: group some_package does not exist - using root".
```

Any hints on how I can improve this approach? Is the problem that the system calls made by shutil/os functions aren't handled by pseudo? Should I replace this Python function with a shell function that can use fakeroot?